# C++ - Split string by regex

Tags: c++, regex, string, split

I want to split `std::string` by `regex`.

I have found some solutions on Stackoverflow, but most of them are splitting string by single space or using external libraries like boost.

I can't use boost.

I want to split string by regex - `"\\s+"`.

I am using this g++ version `g++ (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5` and i can't upgrade.

Comment: Right know I am using this functions to split string: http://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/418518 it works only by __single char__. The regex format is correct, I have already used him in one java project. Works brillant.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know C++ much... and I just want to know how to split `std::string` using old c++ standard (`C++03` probably). If you have some links / code just paste it. :) Thanks!

Comment: Can you show example input and desired output?

Comment: Using [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_token_iterator.html) may be an option.

Comment: @melwil: Desired input / output: https://gist.github.com/maciejkowalski/af7e0ce2b92d967e050c

Comment: @Dukeling: Unfortunatelly, I can't use boost. ;/

Comment: If that version of g++ C++11 compliant, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13125497/1711796) / [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) may be a starting point. Otherwise, splitting by regex pattern *without* an external library will probably require writing a regex parser (which is no small task, or a small copy-paste task, assuming you can find code to do it). However, if you just want to split by multiple spaces, a simple iterative solution probably won't be too difficult, or simply split by a single space and ignore empty strings.

Comment: C++03 does not come with a regex library. C++11 does but your compiler won't support C++11. You need to either use an existing third-party regex library, or write one of your own.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to use regular expressions if you just want to split a string by multiple spaces.   Writing your own regex library is overkill for something that simple.

The answer you linked to in your comments, [Split a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c/236803#236803), can easily be changed so that it doesn't include any empty elements if there are multiple spaces.

```
std::vector<std::string> &split(const std::string &s, char delim,std::vector<std::string> &elems) {
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        if (item.length() > 0) {
            elems.push_back(item);  
        }
    }
    return elems;
}


std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string &s, char delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    split(s, delim, elems);
    return elems;
}
```

By checking that `item.length() > 0` before pushing `item` on to the `elems` vector you will no longer get extra elements if your input contains multiple delimiters (spaces in your case)

Comment: Well, we figured out the same way in the same time. :) But you were actually faster (~10 min) in pasting answer on SO. +1 & accept.

Comment: You should agree also on fact that using C++ to split string looks like even larger overkill, in C# you just do `str.split(...)` ;)

Answer (score 64):

```
#include <regex>

std::regex rgx("\\s+");
std::sregex_token_iterator iter(string_to_split.begin(),
    string_to_split.end(),
    rgx,
    -1);
std::sregex_token_iterator end;
for ( ; iter != end; ++iter)
    std::cout << *iter << '\n';
```

The `-1` is the key here: when the iterator is constructed the iterator points at the text that precedes the match and after each increment the iterator points at the text that followed the previous match.

If you don't have C++11, the same thing should work with TR1 or (possibly with slight modification) with Boost.

Comment: @Narek - either that, or add explicit template arguments: `regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator>`. `sregex_token_iterator` is easier. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: the last example on [cplusplus.com reference doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_token_iterator/regex_token_iterator/) is similar to this answer

Comment: For clarification for noobs like me: The default constructor of "std::sregex_token_iterator" creates an "end-of-sequence" object.

Answer (score 17):

To expand on the answer by @Pete Becker I provide an example of resplit function that can be used to split text using regexp:

```cpp
#include <regex>

std::vector<std::string> resplit(const std::string &s, const std::regex &sep_regex = std::regex{"\\s+"}) {
  std::sregex_token_iterator iter(s.begin(), s.end(), sep_regex, -1);
  std::sregex_token_iterator end;
  return {iter, end};
}
```

This works as follows:

```
   string s1 = "first   second third    ";
   vector<string> v22 = resplit(s1);

   for (const auto & e: v22) {
       cout <<"Token:" << e << endl;
   }

   //Token:first
   //Token:second
   //Token:third


   string s222 = "first|second:third,forth";
   vector<string> v222 = resplit(s222, "[|:,]");

   for (const auto & e: v222) {
       cout <<"Token:" << e << endl;
   }

   //Token:first
   //Token:second
   //Token:third
   //Token:forth
```

Comment: This is really a good one. If any one is facing difficulties compiler complaining about can not convert to regex from char* , just write  vector<string> v222 = resplit(s222, "[|:,]"); in to two lines, like std::regex sep_regex = std::regex{"[[|:,]"}; vector<string> v222 = resplit(line, sep_regex);

Answer (score 3):

```
string s = "foo bar  baz";
regex e("\\s+");
regex_token_iterator<string::iterator> i(s.begin(), s.end(), e, -1);
regex_token_iterator<string::iterator> end;
while (i != end)
   cout << " [" << *i++ << "]";
```

prints `[foo] [bar] [baz]`