# why it gave random value from map

Tags: c++

I have a string which is  x = 5  and i spliced it to x 5 then declare a map

```
 map<string, double> variableMap;
```

i put them into a map use

```
variableMap.insert(make_pair(splitString.at(0), stod(splitString.at(1))));
```

`splitString.at(0)` will be x and `stod(splitString.at(1))` will be 5

but when i was trying to get the value from find key by using

```
                 map<string, double>::iterator iter;

                 iter = variableMap.find("x");

                     cout << iter->second<<endl;
```

it prints 6.95321e-310

this is really weird

Comment: could you publish some snippet of your code ?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you must check `iter != variableMap.end()` before using `->` on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely got the splitString wrong, so that the map does not really contain the key "x".  You should check the result of find for equality with variableMap.end() before use.

```
iter = variableMap.find("x");
if(iter == variableMap.end()) {
  // not found ...
}
```

Use a debuger, and verify that the pair has the right content, including white space for the string.

You could also print it to check what it contains:

```
for(auto elem : variableMap) {
   std::cout << ">"<<elem.first << "< " << elem.second << std::endl;
}
```

Edit: as your problem was indeed white space, consider not writing string string manipulations yourself, but instead look at the top answers at [C++ - Split string by regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749069/c-split-string-by-regex)

Comment: yea when i useif(iter != variableMap.end()) {
  cout<< iter->second;
} it doesn't print any thing. so i guess you are right. key may not contain at the map. I'm checking if if string contain white space

Comment: yup, it is the matter of white space, i splitString wrong. thank you soooooo much!!