# Splitting a string by regex cuts away the first letter of result

Tags: c++, regex, split

Consider the code:

```
regex boundary{ "\\s*\\b\\s*" };
string test = "foo bar\t baz-floop";
auto begin = sregex_token_iterator(test.begin(), test.end(), boundary, -1);

for (auto i = begin; i != sregex_token_iterator{}; i++) {
    cout << *i << endl;
}
```

The code was adapted from [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16752826/5899161) and was meant to split the string by regex. The result of calling this (on VC++ 16.2.3) are:

> oo
>
> ar
>
> az
>
> loop

How can I correct the code, so that the first letter of matches are not deleted? I can't change the regex itself. Moreover, the analogous code in Java seems to work according to my expactations:

```
    Pattern boundary = Pattern.compile("\\s*\\b\\s*");
    String test = "foo bar\t baz-floop";
    String[] results = boundary.split(test);
    for (String result : results) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Comment: Buggy standard library? [Works here](https://ideone.com/TpDeiq).

Comment: "Otherwise (if the member regex_iterator is an end-of-sequence iterator), but the value -1 is one of the values in submatches/submatch, turns *this into a suffix iterator pointing at the range [a,b) (the entire string is the non-matched suffix)" from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator/regex_token_iterator. It seems the -1 might be the culprit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in the standard library. Fixed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/commit/62482a6ddd20da0a2d7c3ba69850a9ee579a2be7).